# Android Refresh Activity from Notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have a program in which I call a notification. The notification, if you pull it down, launches a new activity.

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

int icon = R.drawable.stat_sys_secure_green;
CharSequence tickerText = "Browser Security Enabled";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "Browser Security";
CharSequence contentText = "Security Vulnerability Detected";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PrivacyMessage.class);

//Test Extra
notificationIntent.putExtra("Primary Key", "Primary Text");

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

The problem comes later in the code, when I want to refresh the secondary activity. The main activity should be able to dynamically change the extras in it. I tried doing this by launching a new intent.

```
CharSequence contentTitle = "Browser Security";
CharSequence contentText = "Test New Notification";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrivacyMessage.class);
notification.icon = R.drawable.stat_sys_secure_orange;

intent.putExtra("Test Thing", "Test Value");
//intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent cI = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "New Title", "NewText", cI);
mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

Now, when I execute that code, the new notification title pops up, the icon color changes, and the pulldown reflects the new title and addition information. However, when I click on it, it does not launch the activity with the new intent. Instead, it just pulls out the old activity with the old extras. I tried both FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, but neither one seems to clear the old secondary activity and create a new one. Any idea on how I might do that?

Comment: Excuse me for my misunderstanding, but you want to launch a new activity with no history, or you want the old activity to be on the foreground and refresh its status?

Comment: I want the old activity to come to the foreground when the notification is pressed, but be updated with a new intent.

Comment: Can you help with my problem, too?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149685/android-notification-refresh-activity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently this is actually a bug/feature of the android environment. Unless a pendingIntent() is passed with a unique requestCode, it simply retrieves the old intent that was originally passed with that number.

Details can be found here:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ad855bb57042c2bd/e84c8d6fececf6e4?lnk=gst&q=notification#e84c8d6fececf6e4

The solution they came up with was to simply increment the requestCode every time `pendingIntent.getActivity(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)` is called, and set the flags the way I had done it originally with

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Which, doesn't seem like a perfect solution, but it works. Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: Or better use the PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag with PendingIntent.getActivity()

Comment: PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag with PendingIntent.getActivity() works for me

Answer (score 0):

I think, first of all, you should forget about the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, cause this would open a new task (group of activities) without clearing anything you previously opened. The `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` wouldn't vbe useful for you either, cause, if I understand the scenario correctly your taks has only two activities, and your target activity is the secondary.

So here it's my question... If the second piece of code is executed within an Activity context, why don't you just call `startActivity` with the new extras? This would allow you to handle the new extras on the `onStart` method of the secondary activity.

Regards.

Comment: My understanding of startActivity was that it would immediately launch a new Activity. What I want to have happen is to only have it launch the activity from the notification dropdown, but have it be the updated version at that point. 

I tried it, to check, and it launches a new activity immediately, but then throws an android.app.SuperNotCalled exception.

Answer (score 0):

Are you overriding [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)() to catch the new intent, or just calling getIntent()?  The onNewIntent() documentation says that getIntent() will continue to return the original intent used to launch the activity, unless you call setIntent() from onNewIntent().

Comment: I was actually just calling getIntent. I tried just now to add in the simple:
`public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
   this.setIntent(intent);
}`

but it seems to have done nothing. I also just tried copying my onCreate method formatting changes into the onNewIntent method. Neither did much. Any further thoughts?