# Android: activity referesh when noification fire

Tags: android, notifications

Currrently I am working on Notification in andorid.

Here code is notification arrive....

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setTicker("New Task Here!!!");
    if(taskdata.get(0).getDescription().equals(""))
    {
     int stringId = context.getApplicationInfo().labelRes;
     String appname = context.getString(stringId);

     mBuilder.setContentTitle(appname);
    }
    else
    {    
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(taskdata.get(0).getDescription());
    }

    long l = Long.parseLong(taskdata.get(0).getDateTime());

     Date date =new Date(l);

     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a ");
     String alarmtime = formatter.format(date);
     String dateString= DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy",date).toString();


    mBuilder.setContentText(alarmtime+","+dateString);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, TaskDetail.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

    Bundle bundledata = new Bundle();

    bundledata.putString("ImagePath", taskdata.get(0).getImagePath());
    bundledata.putString("Des", taskdata.get(0).getDescription());
    bundledata.putString("DateTime", FlagValue);        
    resultIntent.putExtras(bundledata);

    stackBuilder.addParentStack(TaskDetail.class);

    //ringtone on

    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
    r.play();

    /* Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives */
    mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessages);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Ac   tivity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
   // here this activity will refresh when fire the receive   
    Intent activityintent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);


    PendingIntent contentintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, activityintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    activityintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    activityintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

   mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
   mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

My issue is :

- When Nofification come that time `MyActivity.class` Activity will be refresh.

I am also refer this link [Android Refresh Activity from Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834058/android-refresh-activity-from-notification) but in my application not wok.

If you have Any Idea Please Help me.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: what exactly is happening now ?

Comment: i am creating task remainder application. i have use notification for task remainder. i am add task to particular time.  so when Notification will arrive that time task list activity will refresh and current task will remove from that list. but does not refresh the activity. @ A M

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function in the end of the notification function .

```
 onCreate(null)
```

Comment: @Chirag again Use startActivity(Activity Name)